Presentation-api PresentationRequest crashing browser in MS Edge
I have several webapps that uses the presentation-api to display and update page on secondary display. All worked perfectly well.
I haven't used them in a while. Now all of them crashes the browser when I connect to another display on MS Edge. In Chrome it works 100%.
It does exatly the same on Presentation Receiver API Sample that I found through a previous answer by Wolfgang Fahl. When I start the connection, the browser asks for the display (see popup image). When I select a display, the display opens fullscreen white background, and then the browser crashes so I cannot see console logs.
I know that according to MDN Web Doc the presentation-api is experimental technology.
Are there any flags that needs to be set in Edge that I am not aware of that might have been reset during a Edge update or something?.

